# Understanding Array of pointers

Tags: c, pointers

I am doing something like this;

```
int main()
{
    int *b[2], j;
    for (j = 0; j < 2; j++)
    {
        b[j] = (int *)malloc(12 * sizeof(int));
    } 
    return 0;
}
```

Please tell me what this instruction really means? And how can I pass this array of pointers to a function to access values like `*(B[0]+1),*(B[1]+1)` etc?

Comment: Don't [cast the result of malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: *Please tell me what this instruction really means?* which one ?

Comment: `*(B[0]+1)` can be written as `B[0][1]`.

Comment: You are asking someone to explain your code to you?  What have you tried to pass an array of pointers?

Comment: *"And how can I pass this array of pointers to a function"* -> `MyFunction(b);`

Comment: *"how can I pass this array of pointers to a function"* - the same way you pass an array of *anything* to a function. Declare the formal parameter as a pointer to base-type (here, it is `int **`) and pass the array id as the argument from the caller.

Comment: I want to know what malloc function is doing there? Yes, I want someone to explain my code. That in what manner malloc will allocate memory after declaring array of two integer arrays.

Answer (score 2):

```
int main(void)
{
    int *b[2], j; // initialization of an array of pointers to integers (size = 2)
    for (j = 0; j < 2; j++) // for each of the pointers 
    {
        b[j] = malloc(12 * sizeof (int)); // allocate some space = 12 times size of integer in bytes (usually 4)
    } 
    return 0;
}
```

If you want to pass this array to a function you can just pass b

```
foo(b);
```

Comment: "size = 2" might be misleading; `sizeof b` would not yield 2. Perhaps "length" would be better, or just "an array of two pointers to `int`."

Comment: Mentioning what will be the prototype of foo() will add more value to your answer.